# SQL aggregation into at most 3 date ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I need to write a query in PostgreSQL to aggregate data from a table based on date ranges of at most 3 ranges. Suppose we have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Purchases (
    ID int,
    PriceCents int,
    PurchaseDate date
);
```

What I want is to write a query to :

1- take the earliest purchase date and the latest purchase date and break them to 3 distinct date intervals

2- aggregate the price of all purchases that happened between the calculated time ranges and display it

in other words, suppose we had the following data in the table:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+
| id | price_cents | purchase_date |
+----+-------------+---------------+
|  1 |         200 | 2020-01-11    |
|  2 |         300 | 2020-01-14    |
|  3 |         100 | 2020-02-02    |
|  4 |         500 | 2020-03-13    |
|  5 |         200 | 2020-07-01    |
|  6 |         300 | 2020-11-17    |
|  7 |         100 | 2021-01-01    |
|  8 |         500 | 2021-01-02    |
+----+-------------+---------------+
```

in this case the data spans between `2020-01-11` and `2021-01-02`
when broken to 3 intervals, it gives us:

from `2020-01-11` to `2020-05-09`

from `2020-05-09` to `2020-09-05`

from `2020-09-05` to `2021-01-02`

and we would expect the result to be

```
+------------+--------------------------+
| total_cost |        date_range        |
+------------+--------------------------+
|       1100 | 2020-01-11 to 2020-05-09 |
|        200 | 2020-06-10 to 2020-09-05 |
|        900 | 2020-09-06 to 2021-01-02 |
+------------+--------------------------+
```

This problem would be trivial if I knew the date ranges ahead of time and could "hardcode" the dates into the query, but I don't.

Comment: What do you mean by "at most 3 ranges"? How is the number and length of time ranges determined? Equal length? Equal number of rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want equal sized ranges, then use `ntile()`:

```
select tile, min(purchase_date), max(purchase_date), sum(price_cents)
from (select p.*,
             ntile(3) over (order by purchase_date) as tile
      from purchases p
     ) p
group by tile;
```

That is not 100% satisfying, because the ranges can overlap (the same date can be in two ranges).  The focus is on equal size within the bins.  So, if you want width bins, then you can use date arithmetic:

```
select ceiling((purchase_date - min_pd) / (max_pd - min_pd)) as tile, sum(price_cents)
from (select p.*,
             min(purchase_date) over () as min_pd,
             max(purchase_date) over () as max_pd
      from purchases p
     ) p
group by tile;
```